# iOS - Draw a donut in an view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-graphics

This is really simple, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a view controller with one view in the center. I want to draw something like the circle below:

[image]

The main problem I'm having, is I can't get anytihng to show up on the view. I'm just trying to draw a line right now, but am obviously missing something key. Here is my code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *centerView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIColor brownColor] set];
    CGContextRef currentContext =UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext,5.0f);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext,50.0f, 10.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext,100.0f, 200.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);

}
```

Comment: There's.. a lot of basics missing here. Start with [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156), maybe?

Comment: or you can start with https://github.com/kirualex/KAProgressLabel

Comment: I like UIBezierPath in drawRect:

Comment: you should try the whole thing by sub-classing `UIView`, and put your drawing code inside `drawRect`

Comment: Thanks @RatulSharker. That's what I was missing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with CAShapeLayer.  Here is a playground that illustrates how to do it.  As an added bonus, I threw in the animation.

```
    import UIKit
    import PlaygroundSupport

    class AnimatedRingView: UIView {
        private static let animationDuration = CFTimeInterval(2)
        private let π = CGFloat.pi
        private let startAngle = 1.5 * CGFloat.pi
        private let strokeWidth = CGFloat(8)
        var proportion = CGFloat(0.5) {
            didSet {
                setNeedsLayout()
            }
        }

        private lazy var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
            let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            circleLayer.lineWidth = self.strokeWidth
            self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
            return circleLayer
        }()

        private lazy var ringlayer: CAShapeLayer = {
            let ringlayer = CAShapeLayer()
            ringlayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            ringlayer.strokeColor = self.tintColor.cgColor
            ringlayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
            ringlayer.lineWidth = self.strokeWidth
            self.layer.addSublayer(ringlayer)
            return ringlayer
        }()

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            let radius = (min(frame.size.width, frame.size.height) - strokeWidth - 2)/2
            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: startAngle + 2 * π, clockwise: true)
            circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
            ringlayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
            ringlayer.strokeEnd = proportion


        }

        func animateRing(From startProportion: CGFloat, To endProportion: CGFloat, Duration duration: CFTimeInterval = animationDuration) {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
            animation.duration = duration
            animation.fromValue = startProportion
            animation.toValue = endProportion
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
            ringlayer.strokeEnd = endProportion
            ringlayer.strokeStart = startProportion
            ringlayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateRing")
        }

    }

    let v = AnimatedRingView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v
    v.animateRing(From: 0, To: 0.5)
```